# java - sort ascending

Tags: java, sorting

well my java project is nearly finished, but having one more part to deal with, sorting.  I have to use sorting in ascending order based on an ID number of an employee.  I'm not sure what kind of sort to use, and where to implement it.  Create a new class for it? Let me show you my tester code.  I have faculty/partime//staff/education classes all working.  Code from those classes all show up in TestEmployee.  So any help/tips is appreciated on how to sort my ID numbers.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestEmployee implements EmployeeInfo{


        public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {

        /**
         * Part A: output all employee from Staff, Faculty, and partime.
         */

        double sum=0,total=0;

                Employee[]emp = new Employee[9];
                Calendar staffBirthDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar facultyBirthDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar partimeBirthDate = Calendar.getInstance();

                staffBirthDate.set(1959, 2, 23);// Scott Chan
                emp[0] = new Staff("Chan, Scott", 123, 'M', staffBirthDate, 35.00);

                 staffBirthDate = Calendar.getInstance();

                staffBirthDate.set(1964, 7, 12);// Brian Salinas
                emp[1] = new Staff("Salinas, Brian", 456, 'F', staffBirthDate, 30.00);

                 staffBirthDate = Calendar.getInstance();

                staffBirthDate.set(1970, 6, 2);// Allen Weir
                emp[2] = new Staff("Weir, Allen", 789, 'M', staffBirthDate, 22.00);

                facultyBirthDate = Calendar.getInstance();

                facultyBirthDate.set(1962, 4, 27);
                emp[3] = new Faculty("Im, Lee", 243, 'F', facultyBirthDate, "Full", "PH.D", "Engineering", "3");

                facultyBirthDate = Calendar.getInstance();

                facultyBirthDate.set(1975, 3, 14);// 
                emp[4] = new Faculty("Bui, Thung", 791, 'F', facultyBirthDate, "Associate", "PH.D", "English", "1");

                facultyBirthDate = Calendar.getInstance();


                facultyBirthDate.set(1980, 5, 22);//
                emp[5] = new Faculty("Monreno, Maria", 623, 'F', facultyBirthDate, "Assistant", "MS", "Physical Education", "0");

                 partimeBirthDate = Calendar.getInstance();

                 partimeBirthDate.set(1977, 8, 10);
                emp[6] = new Partime("Lee, Chesong", 455, 'F', partimeBirthDate, 20, 35.00);

                 partimeBirthDate = Calendar.getInstance();


                        partimeBirthDate.set(1987, 9, 15);
                emp[7] = new Partime("Garcia, Frank", 678, 'M', partimeBirthDate, 25, 30.00);

                 partimeBirthDate = Calendar.getInstance();

                        partimeBirthDate.set(1980, 8, 22);//
                emp[8] = new Partime("Alquilo, Roscoe", 945, 'M', partimeBirthDate, 30, 20.00);

                for(int i = 0; i<emp.length;i++)
        {
            if(emp[i] instanceof Staff)
            {
                System.out.println("\n"+emp[i]);
            }//end of if statement
            if(emp[i] instanceof Faculty)
            {
                System.out.println("\n"+emp[i]);
            }//end of if statement

        }// end of for loop

                for(int i = 0; i<emp.length; i++)
                { 
                    sum = ((Employee) emp[i]).monthlyEarning()+sum;
                }
                System.out.println("\nTotal monthly salary for all Employees");

                System.out.println("$"+sum);
                //c
                System.out.println("\nTotal monthly salary for all faculuty");
                for(int i = 0; i<emp.length;i++)
                {
                    if(emp[i] instanceof Faculty)
                    {
                        total = ((Employee) emp[i]).monthlyEarning()+total;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("$"+total);
              // Duplicate a faculty object. test the duplication
                Faculty f1 = (Faculty)emp[4];
                Faculty f2 = (Faculty)f1.clone();
                Education dupl = new Education("PH.D",
                        "Doctor", "4");
                f2.setEducation(dupl);
                System.out.println("\nD Duplicate a Faculty Object"
                        +"\n"+f2.toString());

                // Verify two staff objects are the same

                System.out.println("\nE.Verify two staff objects ");
                Staff s1 = (Staff)emp[6];
                Staff s2 = (Staff)s1.clone();
                         staffBirthDate = Calendar.getInstance();

                Staff s3 = new Staff("Danger, Norman", 456, 'M', staffBirthDate, 25.00);
                if(s1.getBirthdate()==s2.getBirthdate())
                {
                    System.out.print("\nThe two staff objects " +
                            " birthdays"+ " are the same "
                            +"therefore "+true+"\n");
                }
                if(s3.getBirthdate()==s1.getBirthdate())
                {
                    System.out.print(true);
                }

                // Sort employees by ascending employee ID
                System.out.println("\nSort employees by ID");


                {
                    System.out.println("\n"+emp[i]);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd just use [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).  If you need to change the way that the sort works, you can provide a custom `Comparator`

Comment: Alright, i'll look into Arrays.sort.  Nah, I personally don't want to change the way sort works :P.

Comment: `Arrays.sort` only sorts in the "natural" direction.  If you need to, for example, reverse this, you could use a `Comparator`.  If you were to use a `List` instead, you could use `Collections.sort` and `Collections.reverse` to achieve the same thing, but you would need to decide which best meets your needs ;)

Answer (score 2):

You typically wouldn't implement the sort.   You'd use `Arrays.sort` (in your case) or `Collections.sort`.  All you have to do is provide a `Comparator` which define the ordering.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply.  I'm going to check out the links for a better understanding as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Comparator, or set the Class as Comparable.
Then use Arrays.sort()

See example here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: Ok I finished and everything seems to work using Arrays.sort.  However, I'll look into using comparable as well, thanks for the link to Fruit about comparable(I was getting the errors, and that classcode, as I want to test if I can descend the list.  Thanks for your help peeps.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Employee>{
        public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
             return Integer.valueOf(e1.id).compareTo(e2.id);
        }
}

MyComparator myComparator = new MyComparator();
Collections.sort(array, myComparator);
```

Comment: Preesh! I'll have to read about comparator, since it seems it can handle more efficiently than Arrays.sort

Answer (score 0):

It is best to take advantage of Java Sorted Collections like a TreeSet for example:

```
        Collection<Employee> employList = new TreeSet<Employee>(
                new Comparator<Employee>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Employee a, Employee b) {
                        int getBirthDate = a.getBirthDate()
                                .compareTo(b.getBirthDate());
                        if (getBirthDate != 0)
                            return getBirthDate;
                        int getA = a.getA().compareTo(b.getA());
                        if (getA != 0)
                            return getA;
                        return Long.valueOf(a.getB()).compareTo(Long.valueOf(b.getB()));
                    }
                });
        employList.add(new Employee(...);
```

Initiate the collection first. Then start adding the Employee objects. They will be automatically sorted on BirthDate first then A and B fields of the Employee object. You can add as many as you want or remove A and be part and just return a.getBirthdate().compareTo(b.getBirthdate()); if you only need birthdate.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why nobody has already mentioned Comparator.natural().reverse().